# Graphics are not inserting

Tags: graphics, texmaker, code

I am trying to do some practice problem for my class and I wanted to insert graphs from R.I typed in

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\title{Week 1  Practice}
\date{5/30/2018}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Problem 1}
The following are ages of 62 people who live in a certain neighborhood:
\\
2, 5, 6, 12, 14, 15, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 
36, 36, 37, 38, 39,
40, 40, 41, 42, 43, 43, 44, 44, 45, 45, 46, 47, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 56, 57, 
58, 59, 59, 60, 62,
63, 65, 65, 67, 69, 71, 75, 78, 80, 82, 84, 90, 96
\subsection{Part A}
\subsection{Part B}
*Code
\begin{itemize}
  \item neighborhood = c(2, 5, 6, 12, 14, 15, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 
  27, 28, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 36, 37, 38, 39,
             40, 40, 41, 42, 43, 43, 44, 44, 45, 45, 46, 47, 47, 48, 49, 50, 
   51, 56, 57, 58, 59, 59, 60, 62,
             63, 65, 65, 67, 69, 71, 75, 78, 80, 82, 84, 90, 96)
 \item hist(neighborhood)
 \end{itemize}
 \begin{figure}[hbtp]
  \caption{Age}
  \centering
\includegraphics[scale=1,bb=0 0 30 30]{Age.png}
\end{figure}
```

But when I type the code in,The images are never inserted into the PDF viewer that is embedded in Texmaker and on top of that there is no error that the Texmaker notifies me of.I been trying to fix this for 2 hours and I been trying to surf all over the web for help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Does it work without `bb=0 0 30 30`?

Comment: don't use bb and, for bitmaps like png, best not ti use scale either. Can you not get the plot from R in a scalable format such as eps or pdf?

Comment: If I dont use Background Border  then there is a error claiming that  Texmaker does not recognize that size of the image @samcarter . In R, I can the format to PDF but not Eps hower